# nested data.frame

Tags: r, plyr

I have a nested data.frame

```
dput(res)
    structure(list(date = structure(list(pretty = "12:00 PM CDT on August 14,          2015", 
    year = "2015", mon = "08", mday = "14", hour = "12", min = "00", 
    tzname = "America/Chicago"), .Names = c("pretty", "year", 
    "mon", "mday", "hour", "min", "tzname"), class = "data.frame", row.names =    1L), 
    fog = "0", rain = "1", snow = "0", snowfallm = "0.00", snowfalli = "0.00", 
    monthtodatesnowfallm = "", monthtodatesnowfalli = "", since1julsnowfallm = "", 
    since1julsnowfalli = "", snowdepthm = "", snowdepthi = "", 
    hail = "0", thunder = "0", tornado = "0", meantempm = "26", 
    meantempi = "79", meandewptm = "17", meandewpti = "63", meanpressurem =   "1019", 
    meanpressurei = "30.09", meanwindspdm = "11", meanwindspdi = "7", 
    meanwdire = "", meanwdird = "139", meanvism = "16", meanvisi = "10", 
    humidity = "", maxtempm = "32", maxtempi = "90", mintempm = "21", 
    mintempi = "69", maxhumidity = "86", minhumidity = "36", 
    maxdewptm = "18", maxdewpti = "65", mindewptm = "15", mindewpti = "59", 
    maxpressurem = "1021", maxpressurei = "30.15", minpressurem = "1017", 
    minpressurei = "30.04", maxwspdm = "19", maxwspdi = "12", 
    minwspdm = "0", minwspdi = "0", maxvism = "16", maxvisi = "10", 
    minvism = "16", minvisi = "10", gdegreedays = "29", heatingdegreedays = "0", 
    coolingdegreedays = "14", precipm = "0.00", precipi = "0.00", 
    precipsource = "", heatingdegreedaysnormal = "",           monthtodateheatingdegreedays = "", 
    monthtodateheatingdegreedaysnormal = "", since1sepheatingdegreedays = "", 
    since1sepheatingdegreedaysnormal = "", since1julheatingdegreedays = "", 
    since1julheatingdegreedaysnormal = "", coolingdegreedaysnormal = "", 
    monthtodatecoolingdegreedays = "", monthtodatecoolingdegreedaysnormal = "", 
    since1sepcoolingdegreedays = "", since1sepcoolingdegreedaysnormal = "", 
    since1jancoolingdegreedays = "", since1jancoolingdegreedaysnormal = ""),   .Names = c("date", 
    "fog", "rain", "snow", "snowfallm", "snowfalli", "monthtodatesnowfallm", 
    "monthtodatesnowfalli", "since1julsnowfallm", "since1julsnowfalli", 
    "snowdepthm", "snowdepthi", "hail", "thunder", "tornado", "meantempm", 
    "meantempi", "meandewptm", "meandewpti", "meanpressurem", "meanpressurei", 
    "meanwindspdm", "meanwindspdi", "meanwdire", "meanwdird", "meanvism", 
    "meanvisi", "humidity", "maxtempm", "maxtempi", "mintempm", "mintempi", 
    "maxhumidity", "minhumidity", "maxdewptm", "maxdewpti", "mindewptm", 
    "mindewpti", "maxpressurem", "maxpressurei", "minpressurem", 
    "minpressurei", "maxwspdm", "maxwspdi", "minwspdm", "minwspdi", 
    "maxvism", "maxvisi", "minvism", "minvisi", "gdegreedays",      "heatingdegreedays", 
    "coolingdegreedays", "precipm", "precipi", "precipsource",    "heatingdegreedaysnormal", 
    "monthtodateheatingdegreedays", "monthtodateheatingdegreedaysnormal", 
    "since1sepheatingdegreedays", "since1sepheatingdegreedaysnormal", 
    "since1julheatingdegreedays", "since1julheatingdegreedaysnormal", 
    "coolingdegreedaysnormal", "monthtodatecoolingdegreedays",     "monthtodatecoolingdegreedaysnormal", 
    "since1sepcoolingdegreedays", "since1sepcoolingdegreedaysnormal", 
    "since1jancoolingdegreedays", "since1jancoolingdegreedaysnormal"
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)
```

and I am using the following command to retrieve data from it

```
df <- data.frame()
df <- rbind(df, ldply(res, function(x) x[[1]]))
```

To use this data frame, I convert it into data table, using `dt <- data.table(df)` and now I know how to work with the data, for instance `dt[.id=="fog"]`.

Is there a more elegant/efficient solution?

The problem was solved by @antoine-sac. It was not necessary to use the `apply` to get the data, it was only a question of "un-nest" the data.

Comment: according to your dput, `res` is already a data.frame. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you binding to an empty data structure?

Comment: @jeremycg I am trying to retrieve specific data, for instance, what was the meantempm in this dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your data is a data.frame and one of its column is `date`. But `date` is a data.frame. As you say it is a nested list. So let's "un-nest" it.

You can simply do (assuming your data is in `data`):

```
df.date <- data$date
# removing incorrectly formated date from data
data$date <- NULL
```

At this point, data is a normal data.frame and df.date is also a basic data.frame.

```
> df.date
                                    pretty year mon mday hour min          tzname
1 12:00 PM CDT on August 14,          2015 2015  08   14   12  00 America/Chicago
```

If you want to merge that with your existing data.frame:

```
# binding df.date with your data
data <- cbind(data, df.date)
```

No need for any kind of apply.

Now if you don't know how to access variables in a data.frame, that's another thing.

If you want, say, `meantempm`, you can simply do `data$meantempm`.

I refer you to beginner tutorial about R, there are plenty to choose from with a google request.

Comment: and after that, to format as a proper date object: `res$date2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(res$year, res$mon, res$mday, res$hour, res$min, collapse=" "), format = "%Y %m %d %H %M")`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I really do not need to use apply. It is easier that way!